# What can I use instead of using this for loop in python

Tags: python, matrix, vector

`a` is a matrix of dimension n by m.
`b` is a matrix of dimension n by m.
each row of matrix is `a` one-hot-representation. Consider m=5, the first row of `a`, for example, is [0, 0, 0, 1, 0] and of `b` is [0, 0, 1, 0, 0].

I want to compare `a` and `b`, row by row, and then report an accuracy.
To report accuracy, I have following peace of code and it works:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    a_element = list(a[i]).index(1.)
    b_element = list(b[i]).index(1.)
    if a_element == a_element:
        true += 1
    else:
        false += 1
result = 100. * true / (true + false)
```

I have very large matrices, therefore it takes time. I want to know if there is a faster way to do that. Thank you in advance.

Comment: That's supposed to work? With `a_element == a_element`? And a [mre] including example data would help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use [numpy](https://numpy.org/) if you care about the performance of your matrix operations.

you can use `numpy.where()` as an alternative to `.index()` in your code.

Comment: after converting then to the numpy array, I couldn't see how to do that. Do you know any method for that

Comment: added info about `numpy.where()` :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this would work :

```
# Dimensions
n = 100
p = 100

# Example matrices
a = np.random.choice([0,1], size=(n, p))
b = np.random.choice([0,1], size=(n, p))

# Compute the sum of true positives and true negatives
tp_tn = np.multiply(a, b).sum() + np.multiply(1-a, 1-b).sum()

# Compute accuracy
acc = tp_tn / (n * p) * 100
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have two np arrays: a and b.

```
    a = np.array([[0,0,1,0,0],[0,1,0,1,0]])
    b = np.array([[0,1,0,0,1],[0,1,1,0,1]])
    true = np.sum(a == b)
    false = np.sum(a != b)
    result = 100. *true /(true +false )
```

should give you the result